# How much money can an electrical engineering professor earn from grants in the US?

Tags: professorship, reference-request, salary, electrical-engineering

For US universities, I believe electrical engineering professors earn money in two ways:

1. salary from the university, normally $70k to start
2. grants from researching projects involving different companies or other

How much money can an electrical engineering professor earn from grants normally?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Professors typically do not supplement their salary with grants with one very large exception. The grant money can allow them to trade some number of required courses for research time.

The big exception to this is that the typical appointment for a university professor in the US is for 9 months. If the professor wants to teach some summer courses, they can earn 3 more months of their salary for doing that, or they can get grants to fill in that time. The National Science Foundation limits US researchers who are professors to 2 months of summer time funding, though, so to get 12 full months of compensation, a professor will need income from some other source (summer teaching, another agency's grants, industrial grants, consulting, etc).

So, that being said, typically professors cannot increase their salary rate. They can only use it to fill in the months that the university does not usually pay them for. Finally, most universities give the option for their professors to take the 9 months of salary over 12 months of payments, so filling in those 3 months may look like a monthly raise from the perspective of their bank statements.

Comment: Thank you very much. One person, how claimed that is assistant professor in electrical engineering department in Caltech  University, said to me that he earn 100 k$ from university as salary, also, 200 k$ from grants!! Do you think he is lying or not?

Comment: Without seeing his exact words, I can't be sure, but he may have meant that he had brought $200k in grants to the university. That doesn't mean that he got to take it home. Also, most universities do not put a cap on what the professor can charge for their time as a consultant, so he may have spent his summer 3 months charging a business for his time at a very high rate as a consultant.

Comment: His comment is not in English and you may not understand his comment :( He said that he give many projects with grants from companies and his graduated student do them as their thesis, so, he pays their funds from those grants and finally $200k remains for him.

Comment: Is that $200k per year or does it pay 3 months of his salary every summer for a number of years?

Comment: I do not exactly know what he meant :( he said that he recieves 100k from university and 200k from Extramural projects.

Comment: I would take that to mean that he's got $200k to cover his summer salary or more (by buying off courses that he's required to teach) not that he can supplement his salary. It would be unusual if he could do that with grant funds. Maybe you should ask him.

Comment: I wonder whether the assistant professor in question is talking about [consultancy](https://www.enterprise.cam.ac.uk/for-the-university/be-a-consultant/), rather than about standard research grants...?  Or doesn't that exist in the US?

Comment: The OP is about electrical engineering but for what it's worth I understand things can be quite different in the health sciences. It's pretty fuzzy now since it was years ago but an asst dean once told me his researchers can earn up to something like $250k annually and that he paid $80k of it.

Comment: YMMV. I'm not a prof, just around and on grants with many of them. I may have the accepted answer, but it's not authoritative. I gather that some institutions do have arrangements to allow for outside consulting for profs. I just don't know how it works at each of them.Typically, IME, you can't use outside money to change your salary rate, even if you can supplement your earnings.